# Error injecting com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.ActionMetadataProvider

Tags: gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform

I have the following problem:

```
12:45:47.505 [ERROR] [cGui] Error injecting com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.ActionMetadataProvider: Unable to create or inherit binding: No @Inject or default constructor found for com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.ActionMetadataProvider
Path to required node:

com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.RestRequestBuilderFactory   [com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.gin.RestDispatchAsyncModule.configureDispatch(RestDispatchAsyncModule.java:100)]
->; com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.DefaultRestRequestBuilderFactory [com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.gin.RestDispatchAsyncModule.configureDispatch(RestDispatchAsyncModule.java:100)]
->; com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.ActionMetadataProvider [@Inject constructor of com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.DefaultRestRequestBuilderFactory]
```

My `gwt.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.6.1//EN"
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gwtproject/gwt/2.6.1/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to="cGui">
<!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.inject.Inject' />

<!-- Default css -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard' />
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/> -->

<!-- Other module inherits -->
<inherits name='com.gwtplatform.dispatch.Dispatch' />
<inherits name='com.gwtplatform.mvp.MvpWithEntryPoint' />
<!--    <inherits name="de.barop.gwt.PushState" /> -->

<inherits name='com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.DispatchRest' />
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.uibinder.GinUiBinder" />
<!--    <inherits name="com.gwtplatform.mvp.MvpWithFormFactor" />  -->

<inherits name="com.google.gwt.query.Query" />
<inherits name="com.google.common.collect.Collect" />
<!--    <inherits name="com.googlecode.objectify.Objectify" />  -->
<inherits name="com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rpc.DispatchRpc" />

<source path='client' />
<source path='shared' />

<set-configuration-property name="gin.ginjector.modules"
    value="*CENSORED*.client.gin.ClientModule" />
</module>
```

`ClientModule.java`

```
public class ClientModule extends AbstractPresenterModule {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ClientModule.class.getName());

@Override
protected void configure() {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Installing Client Module dependencies");
    install(new DefaultModule());
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "DefaultModule installed");
    install(new SecurityModule());
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "SecurityModule installed");
    install(new ApplicationModule());
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "ApplicationModule installed");
    install(new RestDispatchAsyncModule());
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "RestDispatchAsyncModule installed");
    install(new RpcDispatchAsyncModule());
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "RpcDispatchAsyncModule installed");
    // DefaultPlaceManager Places
    bindConstant().annotatedWith(DefaultPlace.class).to(NameTokens.LOGIN);
    bindConstant().annotatedWith(ErrorPlace.class).to(NameTokens.ERROR);
    bindConstant().annotatedWith(UnauthorizedPlace.class).to(NameTokens.UNAUTHORIZED);
    bindConstant().annotatedWith(RestApplicationPath.class).to("/rest");
    }
}
```

The code is based on [ArcBees carstore](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/tree/master/gwtp-carstore) tag 1.3.1

My dependencies: [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/SL6qvLzu)

What have I tried:

I made sure every enum and DTO is serializable

Tried to fiddle around with gwt.xml

Googled a lot

I've been struggling with this for the past 5 hours.

If I have forgotten to attach some file, or did not give enough details please tell me. I will update this post accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your gwt.xml, `DispatchRest` has to come *before* `MvpWithEntryPoint`. You should read the important notes here as all the gotchas are explained: https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Rest-Dispatch#add-rest-dispatch-to-your-gwt-module

```
<!-- Other module inherits -->
<inherits name='com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rpc.DispatchRpc' />
<inherits name='com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.DispatchRest' />
<inherits name='com.gwtplatform.mvp.MvpWithEntryPoint' />
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.uibinder.GinUiBinder" />

<extend-configuration-property name="gin.ginjector.modules"
    value="*CENSORED*.client.gin.ClientModule" />
```

Also `Dispatch` is a deprecated module, so you should use `DispatchRpc` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much. Great answer with explanation. :)

Comment: This answer just helped me too. It applies not only to MvpWithEntryPoint but also to the regular com.gwtplatform.mvp.Mvp. Turns out the inclusion order is important. You likely saved hours of poking around.